# Add column names in each cell of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below
[image]

I need to add the column name as key value pair inside each cell
eg: {"colname": "Ship Mode label"}

How to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should work to update the dictionaries in place:

```
for col in df:
    for s in df[col]:
        s['colname'] = col
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}], 'B': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]})
```

output:

```
                                  A                                 B
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'colname': 'A'}  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'colname': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand correctly:

reproducible start (this should give you a data frame similar to the one in the image above):

```
DF = pd.DataFrame([[{'value': 'Second Class label', 'frequency': 10309}, {'value': 'India label', 'frequency': 10309}],
         [{'value': 'First Class label', 'frequency': 7505}, {'value': 'USA label', 'frequency': 7000}]],
        columns= ['Ship Mode Label', 'Country Label'])
```

you can add elements to the dict for example by a simple loop like this.

```
for column in DF.columns:
    for row in DF.index:
        DF.loc[row, column]["colname"] = column
```

This should add to each dictionary in the cell the information as required like so:

```
DF.loc[1, "Ship Mode Label"]
```

> {'value': 'First Class label', 'frequency': 7505, 'colname': 'Ship Mode Label'}

hope it helps